# counter in seconds idle jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, idle-timer

i have this function in Idle library, but what i need is to calculate the action time in second, i mean the active time(onclick, onscroll and keypress).

function is:

```
    (function () { 
var minutes = false;
var interval = 1000; 
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 5; 
var idleCounter = 0;
var counter=0;

document.onclick = document.onkeypress = function () {
    idleCounter = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
++counter;; 
 }, 1000);

};

window.setInterval(function () {
    if (++idleCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
    alert(counter);
        document.location.href = "SessionExpired.aspx";
    }
}, interval);
}());
```

this function will wait for 5 seconds, if no action on the page, so i will be redirected to SessionExpired.aspx. if there is action, so am doing ++couter each second.

I need when this counter in seconds.

Thank you.

Comment: can you plz add detail what issue you are facing in code?

Comment: When i alert(counter) i need how many second i was active (click and keypress), but counter is showing strange value like 201 and 200 for 2-5 seconds as active time.

Answer (score 1):

You can just reset the timer

```
var counter;
var counterSeconds;

document.onclick = document.onkeypress = function () {
    idleCounter = 0; // Set counter to 0 on each keypress/page click
    clearInterval(counter) // Every time they click, clear the old interval and start a new one below
    counter = setInterval(function () { // assign the interval to a variable so we can clear it
       if (idleCounter > IDLE_TIMEOUT) { // Check if they've idled too long
            document.location.href = "SessionExpired.aspx"; // Redirect them if they have
       } 
       ++counterSeconds;
       ++idleCounter; // Should increment 1/sec depending on your computer.
    }, 1000); // Ticks at 1000 milliseconds (1 Second)
};
```

Comment: my counter is showing number of actions and not how many second i was active. counter is giving for example 201 (this means 201 clicks +keypress actions).

Comment: @SouheilDiab I updated my answer, which my give you a nicer solution on managing the timeout instead of using multiple timeouts

Comment: what i need is to start the counter everytime i click or keypress and i need to stop this counter if am not active in the page.

Comment: @SouheilDiab That is exactly what my code above does, it acts the way you want, any time somebody interacts with the page, the timer gets cleared and restarted, `idleCounter` resets back to zero and starts counting up in seconds, if it gets greater than the timeout it redirects. If I'm missing something please let me know.

Comment: yes this is correct dear, but i need the counter value in second (counter means the active time in the page if i click or keypress)

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is that you start new interval function for each click or keypress event which causes multiple threads to update same variable.

You should start an interval thread outside the event.

try this:

```
document.onclick = document.onkeypress = function () {
    idleCounter = 0;
};

var activeTimer = setInterval(function () {
   ++counter; 
}, interval);

var idleTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (++idleCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        alert(counter);
        document.location.href = "SessionExpired.aspx";
    }
}, interval);
```

Comment: its working for me on leaving idle it alert 5 and on clicking active timer get increase. Or may be i didn't understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i wanted exactly and i did it:

```
    <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
      <script src="./e-lawyer/JS/idle.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>timertest</title>
    <script language="javascript">
    var it;
    x = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.status').html('active');
    });


    function count() { 
    x+=1;
    $('.usercount').html(x);
    }

    (function() {

var timeout = 2000;

$(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function() {
clearInterval(it);    
    $('.status').html('idle');
});


$(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function() {
  it = setInterval(count, 1000);
 $('.status').html('active');
});
       $.idleTimer(timeout);

    })(jQuery);

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="status" style="border:1px dashed black; width:500px; height:50px;"></div>
    <div class="usercount"style="border:1px dashed black; width:500px; height:50px;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```